# Rosenberg-Coleman effect

Tags: electromagnetism, sun, magnetic-fields

I know only that it states some variations of the Sun's magnetic fields. What is the [Rosenberg-Coleman effect](http://www.google.com/search?q=rosenberg+coleman+effect) specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "Rosenberg-Coleman effect" originates from the article [Heliographic latitude dependence of the dominant polarity of the interplanetary magnetic field](http://www.leif.org/EOS/JA074i024p05611.pdf).  It is also referred to as the "dominant polarity effect".

As the Earth orbits the Sun, the Earth travels above and below the equator of the Sun.  According to Rosenberg and Coleman, the polarity of the interplanetary magnetic field (IMF) at a given location in the solar system, such as Earth, depends upon the corresponding latitude of the Sun.  According to this proposal, the IMF at Earth should be dominated by the southern solar pole from December 7th to June 6, and the northern pole the other half of the year.